# Copy std::stack into an std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, stack

Is the following code guaranteed by the standard to work(assuming st is not empty)?

```
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
int main()
{
   extern std::stack<int, std::vector<int> > st;
   int* end   = &st.top() + 1;
   int* begin = end - st.size();
   std::vector<int> stack_contents(begin, end);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

`std::stack` is just a container adapter.

You can see that `.top()` is actually (§23.3.5.3.1)

```
reference top() { return c.back(); }
```

Where `c` is the container, which in this case is a `std::vector`

Which means that your code is basically translated into:

```
   extern std::vector<int> st;
   int* end   = &st.back() + 1;
   int* begin = end - st.size();
   std::vector<int> stack_contents(begin, end);
```

And as `std::vector` is guaranteed to be continuous there should be no problem.

However, that does not mean that this is a good idea. If you need to use "hacks" like this it is generally an indicator of bad design. You probably want to use `std::vector` from the beginning.

Comment: +1 you could have just edited your deleted response & undeleted that.

Comment: I see, will do that in the future.

Comment: Some algorithms dictate the use of a stack, and need to return the stacked elements in some other (usually array or vector) form at the conclusion (e.g., topological sort of a DAG).  Doing so using the standard stack adapter instead of rolling your own is IMHO preferred.  Manually popping all the elements off of the stack at the end is slower than necessary, and considering the code here is completely compliant and correct, I see nothing wrong with it.  It's a good pattern to keep in one's toolbox when needed.

Answer (score 6):

Only `std::vector` is guaranteed by C++03 to have contiguous elements ([23.4.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3126.pdf)). In C++1x this will be extended to `std::string` as well ([defect #530](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#530)).

Comment: Wow, I never knew string had no such guarantee. Interesting, thanks. Upvoting, although this is irrelevant to my question

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's guaranteed. Vectors are guaranteed to use contiguous storage, so your code will work. It's a bit cludgy though - and if someone changes the underlying container type of the stack, your code will continue to compile without errors, yet the runtime behaviour will be broken.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a reference to the standard to back this up unfortunately, but there aren't many ways in which it could go wrong I guess:

- Specifying `std::vector<int>` as the container type means that the elements must be stored in a `std::vector<int>`.
- `st.top()` must return a reference to an element in the underlying container (i.e. an element in the `std::vector<int>`. Since the requirements on the container are that it supports `back()`, `push_back()` and `pop_back()`, we can reasonably assume that `top()` returns a reference to the last element in the vector.
- `end` therefore points to one past the last element.
- `start` therefore points to the beginning.

Conclusion: Unless the assumption was wrong, it must work.

EDIT: And given the other answer's reference to the standard, the assumption is correct, so it works.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/), `std::stack` uses a container class to store elements.

I guess what you suggest works only if the containter store its elements in a linear way (`std::vector`).

As a default, `std::stack` uses a `std::deque` which, as far as I know, doesn't meet this requirement. But If you specify a `std::vector` as a container class, I can't see a reason why it shoudln't work.

Comment: That's why he specified `std::vector<int>` as the container type I guess :)

Comment: @sgolodetz: Just realized this ;) I'm still not fully awake right now.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: initial statement redacted, the standard actually does provide a full definition for the stack adaptor, nothing left to implentors.  see top answer.

You want a container that has a push and pop method and allows you to inspect elements anywhere in the container and uses a `std::vector` for storage.  There is such a container in the standard template library

it is called `std::vector`.

Use `std::stack` only for bondage purposes